# Java apps are lagging

Tags: 14.04, java

My graphics card is AMD RADEON HD 6670 and I have my video drivers installed. But my java apps are still lagging. Not all only those which I used Canvas class and game loops. How can I fix that?

Comment: Maybe related: [Program stutters when mouse is still](http://askubuntu.com/q/786214)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to fix it and why does this happen

Comment: I will try this with the mouse but I dont think the problem is in the code because when I was on windows everything worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sloved] Actually it is code problem. After drawing I wrote `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();` and it works perfectly. I don't know why my code worked good on windows without `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();`.

Comment: While java is meant to "write once, run anywhere" this doesn't work automagically. Java *provides* all the necessary tools to write cross-platform applications, but you will need to *test* your application on different platforms to be sure. So in essence, for developers, it's "write once, test everywhere".